# PHP - Check if appointment overlaps available spots

Tags: php, sql

I'm currently working on a appointment system and most of it worked out. Only the part where the visitor has to select the time is very hard to me. I've been struggling with this for a while and decided to reach out to SO.

The idea: If a visitor wants to book the timewindow 10:00 to 13:00, then 10:00, 11:00 and 12:00 should not be displayed anymore after the booking.

[image]

When a different visitor wants to book, these timewindows should not be displayed.

I've been trying to get this to work for a while but only managed to remove 10:00, but 11:00 and 12:00 will remain available. I hope someone can help me on how I should calculate this.

#### The database structure

I have a table called `appointments`. It looks like this:

```
id | user_id | saloon_id | treatment_id | date       | time  | time_end
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
x  | x       | x         | x            | 2021-02-26 | 10:00 | 13:00
```

My code to display the timewindows looks like this:

```php
$opening = strtotime($salooninfo['opening_time']);
$closing = strtotime($salooninfo['closing_time']);

while ($opening < $closing) {
    $start = strtotime('+' . $duration . ' minutes', $opening); // $duration = duration of treatment (example: 30 (=30min))
    
    $time = date('H:i', $start);
    $time_end = date('H:i', strtotime($time . ' +' . $duration . ' minutes'));
    
    $check = $system->query('
        SELECT *
        FROM appointments
        WHERE
        saloon_id = :saloon_id AND
        date = :date AND
        CAST(time as time) >= :start AND
        CAST(time as time) < :end
    ');
    $check->execute([
        ':saloon_id' => $_SESSION['saloon_id'],
        ':date' => $_SESSION['appointment']['date'],
        ':start' => $time,
        ':end' => $time_end
    ]);
    
    if(strcmp($time, $salooninfo['closing_time']) !== 0) {
        ?>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <a href="" class="btn btn-primary d-block time-button" data-time="<?= $time; ?>"><?= $time; ?></a>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help. My brain has nearly melted away.

Comment: Your loop seems to never end, is that why your brain melted? Helping you with this code will be quite difficult, because we cannot run it. I think you should be more precise about the time windows. It is probably easier, overall, if you use an absolute `datetime` field for the start time, and then a simple integer for the duration in minutes (or seconds). That would make it easier to find any overlap.

Comment: If it's 10 **to** 12, then shouldn't 12 still be available? What you're describing is 10 **through** 12 (meaning it includes the hour from 12 to 13 as well).

Comment: @El_Vanja good eye, I've edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have and infinite loop

```
while ($opening < $closing)
```

I think you may correct your sql with (time_end not time)

```
CAST(time as time) >= :start AND    
CAST(time_end as time) < :end//changed here
```

Next, I present to you how I would approach the question.

1- I will collect all the reservations for a day and a fair;

2- I will buckle through all the opening hours of the show, excluding the reserved slots.

Tested and ok here https://phpsandbox.io/n/appointments-tkdbx

```
// For testing only, create table and insert data
$myPDO = new PDO('sqlite:database.sqlite');

$create = $myPDO->query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS appointments
(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, saloon_id INTEGER, date DATE, time TIME, time_end TIME)");

$insert = $myPDO->query("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO appointments
(id, saloon_id, date, time, time_end)
VALUES
(1, 1, '2021-02-26', '10:00', '13:00'),
(2, 1, '2021-02-26', '07:00', '08:00'),
(3, 1, '2021-02-26', '14:00', '16:00')
");

// Get all slots reserved for a saloon and a day
$appointments = $myPDO->query("SELECT * FROM appointments
  WHERE saloon_id = 1 AND date = '2021-02-26'");

// Get time and time_end from query
$booked = array();
foreach($appointments as $appointment)
{
    // Minus 1 hour on time_end
    $date_raw = new DateTime($appointment['date'].' '.$appointment['time_end'].':00');
    $date_raw->modify("-1 hours");
    $appointment['time_end'] = $date_raw->format('H:i');

    array_push($booked, $appointment['time']);
    array_push($booked, $appointment['time_end']);
}

// Create an array of reserved slots
for ($i=(int)$booked[0]+1; $i < (int)$booked[1]; $i++) {
  array_push($booked, $i);
}

// Hard set opening and closing times for testing
$opening = date('H', strtotime("07:00"));
$closing = date('H', strtotime("18:00"));

// Loop through all the opening hours
for ($i=(int)$opening; $i < (int)$closing; $i++) {

  $formatedHour = str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT).':00';
  $disabled = '';

  // Disabled if already booked
  if (in_array($i, $booked)) {
    $disabled = ' disabled';
  }
  echo '<input type="button" value="'.$formatedHour.'"'.$disabled.'>';

}
```

Return

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, no rows are selected if I execute this query

Comment: Try to echoing your final sql query and show us the result please. And what is your SGBD ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. How would I implement this query into my existing code? I'm using phpmyadmin

Comment: @AppelFlap, I don't really understand your approach to listing and excluding time slots. I'm looking on it. I'll get back to you as soon as possible.

Comment: @AppelFlap, I have explained the solution to you in the answer.